# Classification of octonionic reflection groups

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, classification, octonions, reflection-groups

I know that there exist classification theorems for real, complex, and quaternionic, reflection groups.

There are presentations for the real reflection groups, as well as further presentations for the complex ones. The ones for the quaternions and the complex numbers are less familiar, and, from what I can see, their Dynkin diagrams and Weyl symbols are not standardised like the real ones. There are also the three infinite families (discussed by Broué, Malle, and Rouquier in their paper on complex reflection groups).

I did try to see if anyone had attempted to classify the octonionic reflection groups. But as far as I could tell, no one has attempted to derive the complete set. If this has already been done, then please refer me to an open access source. If not then this’ll probably be an open problem, but I am nowhere near experienced enough in the topic of reflection groups to even attempt a classification.

Here is the paper on complex reflection groups:
[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~rouquier/papers/banff.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Erouquier/papers/banff.pdf)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the two lists don't add to the question and just make it longer than necessary, so you should remove them. It would be more helpful to include a definition of octonionic reflection group.

Comment: I don’t know the exact definition of an “octonionic reflection”. As I said, I am rather inexperienced. All I could find were “octonionic  *hyperbolic* reflection groups” which are not what I am asking about. I am asking about *finite* groups.

Comment: Are octonionic reflection groups supposed to be associative (like groups) or not associative (like the octonions)? // Could you post your reference on octonionic hyperbolic reflection groups?

Comment: I did say octonionic reflection *groups* which would by definition, imply associativity. here is the reference to  *hyperbolic* octonionic reflection groups: http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/allcock/research/oh2.pdf

Comment: It seems a hyperbolic octonionic reflection groups are contained in the symmetry group of the hyperbolic octonionic plane, so finite octonionic reflection groups are contained in the symmetry group of the (compact) hyperbolic octonionic projective plane, which is the compact form of $F_4$. Specifically, I think a reflection is supposed conjugate to an order $2$ element of $\mathrm{Spin}_9 \subset F_4$ that's not central. So this gives a definition: a finite subgroup of $F_4$ generated by elements in that conjugacy class.

Comment: So now that we have a definition. I’ll ask again if they’ve ever been fully classified. I’m certain that 2Co₁ (Rank 3) is one of them, although I can’t be certain about the others.